# Authenticate transaction in Web3.js application with password

Tags: web3js, transactions, password, authentication

I have a simple web3.js based app and like to call a method from an contract.

For this method an authenticaten is needed. I found some examples in the web using `web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction`
But in this case, I need the private key.

Waht I need is something like `web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount`, which unlock the account not for an time range, but for the transaction only.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [BatchRequests](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#batchrequest) to unlock, send a transaction, and then lock your account. You can see `lockAccount` at the bottom of the `personal` section under TODO, it is implemented just not documented.

I believe that this still opens up a window of opportunity for someone else to hit the API and send a transaction that you don't want, but it is at least tiny.

I'd recommend not using your Ethereum node to handle private keys. Possibly create an intermediate proxy service if you don't trust the frontend user.

Answer (score 0):

Your dApp users use a wallet like MetaMask that will do this for your dApp:

https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md